# What is the Mark and Space of Ir remote of Airtel?

Tags: arduino-uno, ir, remote-control

Can you please tell me to find out Airtel IR Remote Mark and Space coding. I am making a project in which i have to Airtel IR Remote But I do not have decoding style of it. So please help me out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Isn't it a standard ir-protocol? The IRremote library supports raw ir-data.

Comment: I have tried IRremote library of arduino, But it is not decoding the Airtel ir remote code. I found that there is no protocol set for airtel in its library. So if you have any idea please suggest me.

Comment: Just write a simple sketch, that logs the lengths of marks and spaces to the serial console. I did just that to decode the Samsung TV remote protocol. I loaded the values into excel to easily get the min and max lengths etc.

Comment: I have tried that too,  #Gerben, but getting the garbage output ( mark and space ). Th is is not able to distinguish between the header, bit- mark & space. All are coming same. And the main part, it is not giving the code length that I am sending through Airtel ir remote.

Comment: If it's garbage, then there is something wrong. Are you using the correct frequency receiver? Could you post a sample output. There aren't a lot of people from India here.